# GitHub-pages displayed in raw text format with html tags

Tags: github-pages

I just committed a GitHub-pages with h-t-t-p-s://username.github.io following the [instruction](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site). The file name is `index.html` and it is under `main` branch. The `index.html` was tested on [w3schools.com html editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) and was shown as html file correctly (no html tags). However when displaying on GitHub.io, it shows a raw text file with html tags such as `<!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, <body>, <p>, <li>` and etc. What is missing here with the config of the GitHub-pages?